# Cannot add my own music to my iPhone using the Music App

Tags: iphone, ios, music

New iPhone user here.

I have a few mp3s from music that I recorded myself.

I cannot seem to find a way to add them to my phone.

I have them on 'Music' on my computer and can play them normally, however, when I try to drag them to my phone nothing happens ... I can do the same thing with any other mp3 but not these ones.

Am I doing something wrong? How may I accomplish this?

Edit: Some details I missed that you are kindly asking about. I'm using MacOS, using 'Music', the 'Music' app that used to be iTunes. And they are on my library already, I just can't make them appear on the iPhone. All other tracks work just fine, but these ones don't.

Comment: Are you using iTunes or Finder to move your music?

Comment: Is it even macOS, or Windows? 'Music' is a bit generic. "Dragging to the phone' feels a bit Windows to me [though I've never used the new setup in Catalina].

Comment: You should be able to add music to the music.app and then sync your phone. There are options that might cause problems there, like managing your music manually instead of just syncing your whole music library. Plug in your phone and check what settings you have set to sync music. BTW you **just can't** "drag music to your phone" you add it to your library and then iTunes (or Finder in Catalina) syncs for you.